# How to merge three models together, and use .all(), which gets all posts from those three models in django?

Tags: python, django

So, i have three models. Those three models are used for posts. when people click create posts, those models are triggered. Now i want to get the user's posts for all of those models. But i don't know how to do that all in one.

i could do :

```py
current_user = request.user
d = current_user.onemodel_set.all() # the onemodel is an example model
d = current_user.twomodel_set.all() # the twomodel is an example model
d = current_user.threemodel_set.all() # the threemodel is an example model
```

but, i want to do this.

```py
d = current_user.allpostmodel_set.all()
```

and the above should get the user's posts from all of those models, all grouped together.

So could someone please help me with this?

**my three models**

```py
class AskSection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_pin = models.BooleanField()
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User,  related_name='likes', blank=True) 
    is_marked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_posted']
        verbose_name_plural = "Ask Section"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)



class TutorialsSection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="likes_T", blank=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_posted']
        verbose_name_plural = "Tutorials Section"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)


class AnnouncementsSection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User,  related_name='likes_A', blank=True)
    is_pin = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_posted']
        verbose_name_plural = "Announcements Section"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

So those are my models. Someone please tell me how to get the user's set of all of their posts from those three models into one.

Comment: All of your models have some common fields meaning ideally these common fields should be in one model and the uncommon ones should be in other models that have a one-to-one relationship with this one.

Comment: uh so, could you give me some code for this? Thanks!

Comment: So you want users data of all three model?

Comment: Yes. So when i call `_set.all()`, it should give the posts made by the user in all three of those models. Thanks!

Comment: @shaswat kumar yes. Please.

Comment: @TheKingfisher cant you do something like this set.add(AskSection.objects.value_set('user')), set.add(AskSection.objects.value_set('user')) etc The set will have distinct data

Comment: uh, i don't really get it. Could you show me some code? Thanks!